# Pass Data to Container View Swift

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uicontainerview

I am trying to implement a feature similar to the Spotlight Search on iOS, does anyone know how they do this in Swift?

For mine the search bar will be at the top of the page so I don't need to swipe down to get it to appear, but I do want a blurred effect to appear over my view, but I am going to work on that later. Right now I have a UIContainerView that shows up when you click into the search bar. The UIContainerView has a table view in it, and I am having trouble passing the search results from the original view controller to the UIContainerView so I can populate the table view with the results.

I have tried to use the segue to pass the data but it doesn't seem to work...and it also seems that the container view's ViewDidLoad is called at the same time as the parent view's ViewDidLoad and I need the container view to get the results from the search dynamically when the user is typing in the search bar. I have the search functionality working fine, it is inside func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) so the results are dynamic, but I just can't figure out how to dynamically populate the results in the table view.

In func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String), I have tried but it doesn't work

```
    self.containerView.hidden = false
    let searchResultsVC = childViewControllers.first as! SearchResultsViewController
    searchResultsVC.results = results
```

Comment: Please include [what you have tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) in your post.